# tableview not displaying firebase users

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having a problem with my tableview not showing prototype cells. I have properly named each cell and Identifier. Here is my current code: (Thanks!)

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
class UsersTableViewController: UITableViewController {



@IBOutlet var tableview: UITableView!

var ref: DatabaseReference!

var user = [User]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getusers()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func getusers() {
    let ref = Database.database().reference()

    ref.child("users").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let users = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] ?? [:]

        for (_, value) in users
        {
            if let uid =  users["uid"] as? String
            {
                if uid != Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
                {
                    let showUser = User()

                    if let fullname = users["fullname"] as? String, let imagePath = users["urlImage"] as? String
                    {
                        showUser.fullname = fullname
                        showUser.imagePath = imagePath
                        showUser.userID = uid
                        self.user.append(showUser)
                    }

                }


            }

        }
        self.tableview.reloadData()
    })

    ref.removeAllObservers()
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableview: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableview: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! UserCell

    cell.nameLabel.text = self.user[indexPath.row].fullname
    cell.UserID = self.user[indexPath.row].userID
    cell.userImage.downloadImage(from: self.user[indexPath.row].imagePath!)
    checkFollowing(indexPath: indexPath)

    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableview: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return user.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableview: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let key = ref.child("users").childByAutoId().key

    var isFollower = false

    ref.child("users").child(uid).child("following").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

        if let following = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
            for (ke, value) in following {
                if value as! String == self.user[indexPath.row].userID {
                    isFollower = true

                    ref.child("users").child(uid).child("following/\(ke)").removeValue()
                    ref.child("users").child(self.user[indexPath.row].userID).child("followers/\(ke)").removeValue()

                    self.tableview.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
                }
            }
        }
        if !isFollower {
            let following = ["following/\(key)" : self.user[indexPath.row].userID]
            let followers = ["followers/\(key)" : uid]

            ref.child("users").child(uid).updateChildValues(following)
            ref.child("users").child(self.user[indexPath.row].userID).updateChildValues(followers)

            self.tableview.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
        }
    })
    ref.removeAllObservers()

}


func checkFollowing(indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    let ref = Database.database().reference()

    ref.child("users").child(uid).child("following").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

        if let following = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
            for (_, value) in following {
                if value as! String == self.user[indexPath.row].userID {
                    self.tableview.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
                }
            }
        }
    })
    ref.removeAllObservers()

}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
 // MARK: - Navigation

 // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
 // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
 // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
 }
 */

}
```

I am currently using Google's Firebase API for user storage. In this code I am trying to fetch users to my tableview, only my table view is not displaying any information. Thank you in advance if you are able to help!

Comment: Is this `self.user.append(showUser)` getting called any time? Have you checked?

Comment: @Oxthor Hi! I'm new to swift, and I don't fully understand the question. However, I do know that I am appending my user information to my users array, which should add rows by using user.count.

Answer (score 0):

Remove ref.removeAllObservers() line. Method observeSingleEvent removes observers automatically after completion execution. So in your case ref.removeAllObservers() can remove them before completion invokes and therefore any code in completion doesn't execute.

Comment: Sorry, and thank you for suggestion. However, I tried what you suggested but my tableview is still not displaying any cells.